# Translate 50% didn't work with width 1px in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Why translating a element by 50%, makes with renders incorrectly?

In Firefox is working.

The pen self-explains all:

http://codepen.io/rdsedmundo/pen/wWNqKw

```
.line {
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.translate50 {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a problem based on the units, as it involves pixels and percentages, and only happens in odd numbers.

5 minutes after post here, I managed to "solve" using a hack: leave the element width of 1px and the background color the same as the container, and add a border on the left (or right), also measuring 1px, and the color line that I intended (in this example, red).

```
.line {
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.translate50 {
  transform: translateX(50%);
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have half a pixel, so rounding is involved for odd numbers.